# I have a camera flutter project, I am having trouble making a custom preview camera, is there anyone here to help me what package should I use?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, camera, preview

/// Display Camera preview.

```
Widget _cameraPreviewWidget() {
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return const Text(
        'Loading',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.pink,
          fontSize: 20.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        ),
      );
    }




    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
      child: CameraPreview(controller),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an image from the gallery/camera use [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker).

If you want to crop an image before saving use [image_cropper](https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper)